# Grails Facebook Authentication plugin does not open FB auth page

Tags: facebook, grails, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to use Grails Facebook Authentication plugin.

My goal is to use the Server Side Authentication, which is the default one.

As per the docs

> It's preferred and a standard Login for Server-side Apps. After clicking on 'connect button' user gets redirected to special Facebook page, for authentication, and then redirected back to your app.

I was expecting to get the special FB page, but it's redirecting to straight to
/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect instead. No FB page is showing up.

I'm not logged at FB

My config is like:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='br.com.fisgo.security.Credential'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.relation = 'SameObject'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.secret = 'xxxx'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.appId = 'xxxxxx'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.filter.redirect.processUrl='/sign/facebookLogin'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.filter.type='redirect'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.taglib.button.text='Login com facebook'
```

I can't find out the problem.

The error I get on the redirect is:

```
| Error 2013-03-18 09:35:50,307 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR [/].[default] - 
Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
 Message: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed Line | Method 
->> 1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - | 603 | run in 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^ 722 | run . . . in java.lang.Threa
```

I have also found

```
ERROR facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao  - Can't find authority join class (br.com.fisgo.security.CredentialRole). Please configure 'grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName' value, or create your own 'List<GrantedAuthority> facebookAuthService.getRoles(user)'
```

The class is available

Comment: what is happenning next after `/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect`?

Comment: Please add it to your question

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same `Cannot create a session after the response has been committed` error.

The problem was that spring security was not allowing anonymous access to `j_spring_security_facebook_redirect`.  Not sure how you configured grails spring security plugin but in our case this helped:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
....
'/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
....
]
```

To find the cause of your issue try to comment out line 59 `response.sendRedirect(facebookAuthUtils.prepareRedirectUrl(getAbsoluteRedirectUrl(), facebookAuthUtils.requiredPermissions))` in `FacebookAuthRedirectFilter`.